# Extension - new popup window with parameters from previously open tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

To explain the goal: I am trying to make an extension that opens a new popup window and inside that window I call a function with 2 parameters: the origin and the value of one parameter (view) from the URL where i was before.

So for example, if we click the extension's icon when the current tab is at https://www.base.com/list?view=2abc&tag=new
i want to open a new window, and in that window i will use 2 variables:

```
originURL = https://www.base.com/
```

and

```
view_id = 2abc
```

So, I added this listener to my background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("newpage.html"),
    type : "popup",
    height: 600, 
    width:1300
  });
});
```

and in my newpage.html i call a script which starts with this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  if (!tabs[0]) { console.log('Could not get current tab'); return; }
  let baseurl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
  let originURL = baseurl.protocol + '//' + baseurl.hostname;
  alert(originURL);            
  let view_id = baseurl.searchParams.get('view');
  alert(view_id);            
})
```

but I always get the url as being "chrome-extension://...." which i assume is the extension i am making.

How can I get the url from my initial tab? Perhaps there is a simpler way than the above code...

Thanks

Comment: You can append those parameters to newpage.html's URL in windows.create.

Comment: @wOxxOm you save the day again!